# Error while restart Apache2 inside the container

Tags: linux, apache, docker, containers, httpd.conf

While trying to create a lamp stack in docker container, after configuring files 
when try to restart with command

```
service apache2 restart
```

It throws error

```
[....] Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 99: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
Setting ulimit failed. See README.Debian for more information.
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

Even i've tried with

```
service apache2 reload
apache2 graceful
```

Comment: Also, looks like a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something else is using the port clearly, try this command to find out who is using port 80

```sh
netstat -plnt
```

If you are not using that application, then kill it.

```sh
kill -15 <pid>
```

then you restart the apache server again

```sh
service apache2 reload
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

You almost never use commands like `service` or `systemctl` around Docker containers.  If you need to restart the service running in a container, stop, delete, and restart the container

```
docker stop my-apache
docker rm my-apache
docker run --name my-apache -p ... -v ... httpd:2.4
```

**Deleting and restarting containers this way is extremely routine.**  My sample `docker run` command has a placeholder `-v` option; typically you’d use this to inject configuration into the container at startup time, so that nothing is lost when you do delete the container.